# Translate "Relevement" to english?

Tags: algebraic-topology, translation-request

There is a definition in my French-taught course    that says :

Soient $p:E \rightarrow B$ and $h:X \rightarrow B$ two application continues. Un relevement de $h$ est une application continue $H:X \rightarrow E$ telle que $p \circ H=h$

What is the equivalent term to relevement in english ?

Comment: $H$ is called a "lift" or a "lifting".  See, e.g., [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lift_(mathematics))

Comment: Does the course in French actually say "and" and "two" rather than "et" and "deux"?

Comment: Hahaha , no , it's me by mistake

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $p:E\to B$ and $h:X\to B$ two continuous maps. A *lift* of $h$ is a continuous map $H:X\to E$ such that $p\circ H = h$